# Docker Reverse Proxy To Subdomains

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy

I am attempting to use the jwilder/nginx-proxy docker image to act as a reverse-proxy for two other containers, one of which runs tomcat, the other runs grav. I want them proxied to different subdomains, which shouldn't cause a conflict.

What I want is the following:

- Grav is available on www.domain.com via port 80
- Tomcat is available on appserver.domain.com via port 8080
- The ability to run another app on port 80, pointed to another subdomain.

Currently, both containers use port 8080 as shown by the command `docker ps -a`.

Below is my current docker-compose.yml:

```
nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

tomcat:
    image: tomcat:8.5.15-jre8
    container_name: tomcat
    environment:
        - VIRTUAL_HOST=appserver.domain.com
        - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
#    ports:
#        - "8080:8080"

grav:
    image: garywiz/docker-grav
    container_name: grav
    environment:
        - VIRTUAL_HOST=www.domain.com
        - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
 #   ports:
 #       - "80:8080"
    #expose:
    #    - 8080
    #    - 80

other:
    image: other
    container-name: other
    environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=other.domain.com
    - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
```

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE:**

I changed my docker-compose.yml to the following:

```
version: "2"
services:
    nginx-proxy:
        image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
        container_name: nginx-proxy
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

    tomcat:
        image: tomcat:8.5.15-jre8
        container_name: tomcat
        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=appserver.domain.com
            - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080

    grav:
        image: garywiz/docker-grav
        container_name: grav
        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=www.domain.com,domain.com
            - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
```

Both containers seem to be available via port 80 now, instead of tomcat being available on the "traditional" port 8080. Is this expected behavior based on my config file?

Jason

Comment: Are you using `version: "2"` inside docker-compose.yml? Also, no that grav listen to port `8080` and not 80. Nginx sees only its 8080 port.

Comment: No, being a newbie I hadn't realized that there was a difference in versions. Once I did, I saw them come up, but both on port 80. I posted an update.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that can help you because it's a very simple POC for just a couple of index.html simulating two different projects. Although, maybe with some effort you can get it working for you case.  The trick is to have another container running the nginx as a reverse proxy, that have access to the other containers. Here you have the code https://github.com/jlaso/docker-nginx-reverseproxy-domain-name, probably the feature/production-deployment branch is more useful in a non-local environment.

I written an article explaining that in deep, but it's in Spanish http://developer.joseluislaso.es/2018/02/resolver-por-nombre-de-dominio-en-docker.html.
I got the idea from https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/03/nginx-reverse-proxy-containerized-docker-applications/

Hope can help you somehow.